# Does deadlifting with steel plates on a deadlift platform damage the floor?

Tags: gym, deadlifts

Does lifting with steel plates on a deadlift platform damage the floor?
This gym doesn't allow metal plates on the deadlift platform, only bumpers. The platform is on the first floor but there is a basement underneath with classes, lockers, and offices.  Anyone encounter this at their gym? Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It can depending on what the platform is made out of, how well it's constructed, and how damaged it is. Deadlift platforms protect the floor by dispersing the force of impact from the weights. Most deadlift platforms are made out of wood with a mat on top. The wood will eventually get smashed and need to be replaced. Once the integrity of the wood is compromised, then the force of impact can be transferred to the floor.

Bumper plates can damage it too, but the force of impact is dispersed in a greater surface area. Steel plates are thinner have have absolutely no bounce so all the force of impact is focused on a very small area. Gyms have this rule in an effort to extend the life of their equipment. When the platform eventually becomes damaged, the bumper plates will be less damaging to the floor underneath.